# transform SQL to createQueryBuilder

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I'm trying to transform this sql

```
 SELECT * FROM user_account
 LEFT JOIN brand ON user_account.id = brand.user_id_id
 LEFT JOIN influencer ON user_account.id = influencer.user_id_id'
```

to a createQueryBuilder, I try this but it's not working

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->from(Brand::class, 'brand')
    ->from(Influencer::class, 'influencer')
    ->leftJoin('brand', 'b', 'ON', 'u.id = b.user_id_id')
    ->leftJoin('influencer', 'i', 'ON', 'u.id = i.user_id_id');
$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query->execute();
```

And I got this error

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 42 near 'brand b ON u.id': Error: Class
> 'brand' is not defined.

Someone can help?
Many thanks

Comment: Does the plain SQL query work?

Comment: Yes the plain SQL query is working

Comment: If I see it right, you didn't get the user_account table with from. You also don't need the from for `brand` and `influencer` but you need to join it right `leftJoin('u', 'brand', 'b', 'u.id = b.user_id')`; and is there a typo with `b.user_id_id`?

Comment: Yes it's good typo but it's not working :/

Answer (score 0):

I have never used doctrine query builder, but after reading the docs I would suggest the following solution:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->from('user_account', 'u')
    ->leftJoin('u', 'brand', 'b', 'u.id = b.user_id_id')
    ->leftJoin('u', 'influencer', 'i', 'u.id = i.user_id_id')
$query = $qb->getQuery();
return $query->execute();
```

NOTE: I left `b.user_id_id` as it is in your example, even though I think there is a typo. Maybe this should mean `b.user_id`. The same for `influencer`.